# How to generate coordinate list from matplotlib line in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I have a 2dline with matplotlib. I need a list of points representing `TREND_LINE`. For example, I have 100 values and I want to get the value of `TREND_LINE[67]`.

```py
x1 = 1
x2 = 100
y1 = 53000
y2 = 89745
TREND_LINE = axes[0].plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])
```

[image: graphic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [np.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```py
>>> x1, x2 = 1, 100
>>> y1, y2 = 53000, 89745
>>> z = np.linspace(y1, y2, x2-x1+1)

>>> z[0], z[-1]
53000.0, 89745.0

>>> z[50]
71558.0808080808
```